# Add MongoDB access to universal-starter project

Tags: mongodb, angular, mongoose

I have been looking at the following Angular Universal starter project by AngularClass:

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

and trying to figure out how to change it so that it communicates with a real database rather than a mocked cache and backend.

What is the best way to edit the code so that it connects to a real MongoDB database in the backend for queries and updates?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already created a MongoDB, and you have created some sort of API to handle the angular calls. All you need is to create a service that calls your DB's API. For example....

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Constants{
    public Server: string = "http://localhost:5000/";
    public ApiUrl: string = "api/Post/";
    public ServerWithApi = this.Server + this.ApiUrl;
}
```

In the example above, the DB and its api would be running locally on my machine from localhost. Then you would call this service from a component that handles your CRUD operations. Here is a link to my github, and how I accomplished this task. Specifically on the angular side, pay attention to my `PostData.Service.ts` and my `app.const.service.ts`.

Git [link](https://github.com/bcrawford11/Angular2-w-CRUD-Api-MongoDb)

p.s. my project is split between `UI` which is all my angular and then `API` which is C# handling all the calls to the DB.